# Converting to long form data with no of columns and column name is generated

Tags: r, reshape

I have the following data frame:

| id | text | expand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text1 | pre |
| 1 | text2 | pre |
| 2 | text3 | pre |
| 1 | text4 | post |
| 2 | text5 | post |
| 2 | text6 | post |

and I want to convert into long format like this:

| id | pre1 | pre2 | post1 | post2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text1 | text2 | text4 |  |
| 2 | text3 |  | text5 | text6 |

Any help with this is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Can you give the logic for te modification

Comment: Yes, so each id should be in one row. if there are multiple pre for any id, they should be in a second column with its corresponding text. Same case with the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the warning about the creation of list-columns in the code below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id,   ~text, ~expand,
   1L, "text1",   "pre",
   1L, "text2",   "pre",
   2L, "text3",   "pre",
   1L, "text4",  "post",
   2L, "text5",  "post",
   2L, "text6",  "post"
  )

df |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = expand,
              values_from = text) |>
  unnest_wider(c(pre, post),
               names_sep = "")
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>      id pre1  pre2  post1 post2
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 text1 text2 text4 <NA> 
#> 2     2 text3 <NA>  text5 text6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>